# Returning The NameS of the highest value field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple products and I have value against them .

I used `min()` to find the least value and then used `Index`,`match` to get the corresponding product name. But I have multiple products that have the same value.

In this Case, the min Value is *54*, So how do I get all three names that are mapped against it for example,it should show *Product A*,*Product P*,*Product Q* against 54.

[image]

At the moment it is showing only Product P

Comment: You can't, not with Excel, You need a database for this.

Comment: You can't with the usual formulas, you'll need to create a VBA Macro to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function FindAll(v As Variant, rng As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long
    ary = rng

    For i = LBound(ary, 1) To UBound(ary, 1)
        If v = ary(i, 1) Then FindAll = FindAll & "," & ary(i, 2)
    Next i
    FindAll = Mid(FindAll, 2)
End Function
```

The pick a cell, say **D7**, and enter:

```
 =MIN(A:A)
```

and in **C7** enter:

```
=findall(D7,A1:B25)
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved with using only functions already available in Excel. I used this [link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/12/09/multiple-occurrences-lookup-and-extraction/) and then tweaked it for your problem. Assuming your products are in column A and your Values are in column B, use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$20,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$20=$E$3;ROW($A$2:$A$20)-1);ROW()-2));"")
```

Enter with ctrl+shift+enter (Array formula) and drag down to view all your occurences.

How does it work? The `if` function first checks if the value in the lookup range is equal to the lookup value and if so it returns the index of that value. (You have to do `row(..)-1` because your data starts in row 2. The `row()-2` at the end is to make sure you get the first, second,... occurence of the minimum as you drag down. The -2 is needed because your formula will come in the third row of the sheet. I finally wrapped everything in an `iferror` function so only the good values will show, and no error messages.

Comment: Clever approach!.................. *(+1)*

Comment: And you learn it, it by also learning a lot about the Hoff. Writer of the linked article stuffed the article with humor, so that's an added bonus

Answer (score 0):

Several non-VBA approaches:

Formula:

With Headers in row 1 and your data in columns `A:B` and `=MIN(Product)` in `E3`:

```
F3: =IFERROR(INDEX(Value,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/(Product=$E$3)*ROW(Product),ROWS($1:1))-1),"")
```

Entered normally and fill down until you see blanks

[image]

You could **sort** the data on Products, then use the following Conditional Format:

Assuming your sorted table starts in `O12` with the first line of data in `O13`

```
=O13=O12

Format As:   Custom Number Format:  ;;;
```

[image]